# Multiple language support in windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application which supports two language, English and Spanish.

In my application I have one XAML page which contains `WebBrowser` control. The problem is when I change phone language to Spanish then all text is displayed in Spanish except the content of `WebBrowser`control.

Comment: What do you display in the WebBrowser? Static content or website?

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` control uses the localization settings for the browser, as set by the user. It can be different from the application localization.

Also, once changed, make sure you don't have any cookies persisting the language selection.